# Retrieving Data from a Submitted Form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit information through a form in separated HTML file from another HTML file where I wanted to retrieve the information.

How can I get the value submitted data in `file2.html` using jQuery and display them?

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataForm = $(this).serialize();     
        $.ajax ({
            type : "POST",
            url : $(this).attr('action'),                   
            data : dataForm,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }               
        });
    });//endsubmit
});//end ready
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form id="form" action="file2.html">                
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Generate signature">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: what you got with your code??

Comment: Are you trying to submit this back to your server? What are you using server-side? Is it PHP, ASP.NET, JSP?

Comment: I am new at this, I am not using any server-side. it is the only way to retrieve the form information in the other html page ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear you one thing you can send the data from html file to html file you need to use server side like PHP or .NET
 for PHP Try this

```
var data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);//this will select all the form data in the data variable.

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"insert.php",
            data:data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(dta)
            {
                alert(dta);
            }

        });
```

You can try this tutorial for complete explanation http://w3code.in/2015/10/insert-data-in-database-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-php-beginner-guide/

Comment: should i create insert.php file?

Comment: yes you need to create the insert.php file to fetch the data

Comment: Thank you. Can i ask you to show me how to fetch the data using php?

Comment: Check the link I have given you